# How to pass unique_ptr<char[]> to a function to use

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, c++11

Here's basically what I want to do:

```
SerialPort::ReadBytes(int32& errcode, Message::string& msg, uint32 num)
{
    DWORD numBytesRead = 0;
    LPDWORD pNumBytesRead = &numBytesRead;
    errcode = 0;        

    std::unique_ptr <char[]> buff (new char[num]);
    // ^^^^ pass this char buffer to the ReadFile function below

    if (!ReadFile(m_sp_pointer,     // Handle to device
            buff,                  // Receives data from device
            num,                    // num bytes to read (in)
            (LPDWORD)pNumBytesRead, // num bytes read (out)
            NULL))
        {
            errcode = GetLastError();
        }

    if (numBytesRead > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I do know that I am not doing this correctly, so my questions are: how do I do this correctly and is there anything that makes this a bad idea?  Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I actually should be passing in the unique_ptr in the parameters instead of locally declaring it and passing in `Message::string& msg`.

My original attempt was to pass the `Message::string` (`std::string`) by reference, so that is an option too.. i.e., instead of using unique_ptr at all.  In *that* case I would use a regular `char[]` locally and then set `msg` contents to the `char[]` and return it.

I am not sure which would be better, it seems that a number of responses recommend `vector<char>` instead. (Would be very similar to using `std::string`).

Comment: I would use a `std::vector<char> buff(num);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you need `std::unique_ptr`. I would prefer `std::vector` in this case:

```
std::vector<char> buff(num);    //and pass buff.data() to function
                                //which accepts char*

if (!ReadFile(m_sp_pointer,               // Handle to device
        buff.data(),                      // Receives data from device
        buff.size(), //(CHANGED THIS TOO) //num bytes to read (in)
        (LPDWORD)pNumBytesRead,           // num bytes read (out)
        NULL))
    {
        errcode = GetLastError();
    }
```

Note that [`std::vector::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) is available with C++11 only. In C++03, you could use `&buff[0]` instead.

Comment: One advantage that `unique_ptr<char[]>` has here is that it does not unnecessarily initialize the data that's about to be overwritten anyway.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley So after thinking about it, I think my question is: what is better if I intend to return the data that I read from ReadFile, a reference to a vector or string or a unique_ptr?

Comment: @Nawaz, what is the reason for preferring vector over std::unique_ptr?

Answer (score 5):

Using smart pointers is good and is quite helpful but there are situations where a raw pointer is the right choice.

My guess is that ReadFile uses the buffer and doesn't store it anywhere - so there is not really a argument for a smart pointer withing the function. Just passt a raw pointer with

```
buff.get()
```

Further comment: 
It makes sense to use a unique_ptr **outside** ReadFile because it can help to handle memory correctly. With "manual memory management" you would need to delete on every path which returns from the functions (e.g. exceptions).

Comment: So Daniel, thanks for the input about using regular pointers locally in functions.  Great advice.  I do, however, need to return this data to a calling function and pass the message around quite a bit after that.  I made an edit to my original question to address this issue.  Basically, I am wondering, for this case, is their a preference for std::unique_ptr or (std::string/std::vector<char>)?

Comment: Actually I've upvoted the answer from Nawaz. I tried to come up with an example where you would prefer an smart pointer to an array instead of a container structure but wasn't able to (maybe someone else?). The only thing I would know of is that you can convert a unique_ptr to a shared_ptr - which in some cases is needed.